# Call a repeating function with different parameters after the previous instance finished

Tags: javascript

I want to call a second instance of the same function but with different values, after the first instance has completely finished, currently it calls both instances at the same time.

```
    function printLetterByLetter(destination, message, speed) {
        var i = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += message.charAt(i);
            i++;
            if (i > message.length) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, speed);
    }

    printLetterByLetter("hc-a", "Hello world", 100);

    printLetterByLetter("hc-b", "Hello world again.", 100);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using `promise` which wait for your first function execution then execute next otherwise you can use `async/await` which is also a good alternative.

Using `Promise`

```js
function printLetterByLetter(destination, message, speed) {
    var i = 0;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += message.charAt(i);
            i++;
            if (i > message.length) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                resolve(true);
            }
        }, speed);
    });
}


printLetterByLetter("hc-a", "Hello world", 100).then(function(resolve) {
    printLetterByLetter("hc-b", "Hello world again.", 100);
}, function(reject) {});
```

Using `async/await`

```js
    function printLetterByLetter(destination, message, speed) {
        var i = 0;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += message.charAt(i);
                i++;
                if (i > message.length) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    resolve(true);
                }
            }, speed);
        });
    }

    (async function() {
        await printLetterByLetter("hc-a", "Hello world", 100);
        printLetterByLetter("hc-b", "Hello world again.", 100);
    })()
```

Comment: I like that second example and it works great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promises or async/await in order to do this. See the example below, that achieves your goal by utilizing Promises:

```js
function printLetterByLetter(destination, message, speed) {
  var i = 0;
  // Return promise instance which you can use to execute code after promise resolves
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      document.getElementById(destination).innerHTML += message.charAt(i);
      i++;
      if (i > message.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        // Resolve promise and execute the code in "then" block
        resolve();
      }
    }, speed);
  });
}

printLetterByLetter('hc-a', 'Hello world', 100).then(function() {
  // This code gets executed when promise resolves
  printLetterByLetter('hc-b', 'Hello world again.', 100);
});
```

```html
<div id="hc-a"></div>
<div id="hc-b"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a classical approach with a stack and test the stack if the actual interval has ended.

```js
var printLetterByLetter = function () {
        function startInterval() {
            var data = stack.shift(),
                i = 0;

            return data && setInterval(function () {
                document.getElementById(data.destination).innerHTML += data.message[i++];
                if (i >= data.message.length) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    interval = startInterval();
                }
            }, data.speed);
        }

        var stack = [],
            interval;

        return function (destination, message, speed) {
            stack.push({ destination, message, speed });
            interval = interval || startInterval();
        };
    }();

printLetterByLetter("hc-a", "Hello world", 100);
printLetterByLetter("hc-b", "Hello world again.", 50);
printLetterByLetter("hc-c", "See you later, alligator!", 200);
```

```html
<div id="hc-a"></div>
<div id="hc-b"></div>
<div id="hc-c"></div>
```